# Inaccessible cardinal and von Neuman Hierarchy

Tags: set-theory

I read a couple of days ago that if $k$ is inaccessible, then $V_k=H(k)$, where $V$ is the von Neumann hierarchy and $H(k)$ the class of sets that are heredititarily of cardinality $< k$.

My question would be: is there any singular $k$ for which $V_k=H(k)$? I managed to show that if $K$ is regular then $V_k=H(k)$ iff $k$ inaccessible or $k=\omega$, but I'm clueless about an example?

Comment: You not not need the regular part. If $\kappa > \omega$, then $V_\kappa = H_\kappa$ if and only if $\kappa = \beth_\kappa$. I have deleted my incorrect example.

Comment: Can't you define by recursion $\kappa_{n+1} = \beth_{\kappa_n}$ and set $\kappa = \bigcup_n \kappa_n$?

Comment: Beware of an ambiguity in the meaning of "hereditarily of cardinality $<k$" when $k$ is singular. The more common meaning nowadays is that the transitive closure of the set $X$ in question has cardinality $<k$.  But one occasionally finds the alternative meaning (closer, in my opinion, to the origin of the terminology) that $X$, all its elements, all their elements, etc. (ad infinitum) each have cardinality $<k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the regular part. If $\kappa > \omega$, $V_\kappa = H_\kappa$ if and only if $\kappa = \beth_\kappa$. (Kunen \textit{Set Theory} 78.)

Define $a_0 = \aleph_0$. Define recursively, $a_{i + 1} = \beth(a_i)$. Let $\alpha = \lim_{i< \omega} a_i$. $\beth(\alpha) = \alpha$. $\alpha$ has cofinality $\omega$. So $\alpha$ is a singular cardinal with $\beth(\alpha) = \alpha$.

I hope it is correct now.

Comment: $\beth_\omega$ is most certainly not $\omega$.

Comment: $\beth_\omega$ is a $\beth$ fixed point? That would mean that $\omega=\beth_\omega$ which is clearly not true.

Comment: @Asaf: why would it imply that?

Comment: @Dalrania: What does a fixed point mean? It means that $\kappa=\beth_\kappa$. So if $\beth_\omega$ is a fixed point we have that $\beth_\omega=\beth_{\beth_\omega}$. But it is easy to prove that $\alpha\mapsto\beth_\alpha$ is injective so $\omega=\beth_\omega$.

Comment: oh, I didn't know the beth function was injective, ok...

Comment: @Dalrania: This is a simple proof based on Cantor's theorem that $\beth_\alpha<\beth_{\alpha+1}$ for all $\alpha$.